# Bug Fixing: Copied images in Excel 2016 VBA appear as blank images

Tags: excel, image, vba

I am trying to export into my local file a defined Excel range as image (PNG) (it’s named: “ Print_Area” on tab “Summary” Range: P1:AI92 ) . The program runs well, however when I open the file all the imagines are blank 
Here is the coding that I am using:

```
Sub _Daily_Mail()

Dim Rango7 As Range
Dim Archivo As String
Dim Imagen As Chart
Dim Result As Boolean

Set Rango7 = Sheets("Summary").Range("P2:AI92")   ' Summary
Sheets("Summary").Select

 With Rango7
      .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
       Set Imagen = Rango7.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(33, 39, .Width, .Height).Chart
    End With

Imagen.Paste
Imagen.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
Imagen.ChartArea.Width = Imagen.ChartArea.Width * 3
Imagen.ChartArea.Height = Imagen.ChartArea.Height * 3

Imagen.export "C:\Users\mely\Documents\Imagenes_POS\Informe1.png", filtername:="PNG"
Imagen.Parent.Delete
Set Imagen = Nothing
```

[When I open the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39lDn.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 2016 you need to use .Activate command before Paste operation.
Example:

```
Set rng = Range("A1:C1")

With rng
    .CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture

    Set oChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(.Left, .Top, 1920, 1080)

    oChart.Activate

    With oChart.Chart
        .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
        .Paste
        .Export Filename:="C:\File.jpg", Filtername:="jpg"
        .Parent.Delete
    End With
End With
```

Comment: That was the hint I needed!
I was creating the Chart in another Worksheet. Just activating that Worksheet before paste also solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same issue with office 2016.  It appears to be a timing issue.  When creating the Chart Object and being able to paste to it.  If I step through the code it works as expected and generates my image.

I came up with a fix which appears to work:
For some reason selecting The chart's parent shape before calling the Paste corrects The issue.

```
Function CopyRangeToPNG(ByRef rngImage As Range) As String
   Dim vFilePath As Variant

   rngImage.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

  With rngImage.Parent.ChartObjects.Add( _
      Left:=rngImage.Left, Top:=rngImage.Top, _
      Width:=rngImage.Width + 2, Height:=rngImage.Height + 2)

    With .Chart
       .Parent.Select
      .ChartArea.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
      .Paste
      With .Pictures(1)
        .Left = .Left + 2
        .Top = .Top + 2
      End With
      ' export
      .Export CStr(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ImageName.PNG")
    End With
    .Delete
  End With
  CopyRangeToPNG = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ImageName.PNG"

End Function
```

Comment: This isn't even close to the same code...if you want to answer this question, then answer it, explaining how your answer addresses OP's problem, instead of writing your own separate set of code.

Comment: @CindyMeister - "the same code" does not mean "the same functionality" - while it may perform the same function, it is most certainly not the same code. Unless I have forgotten how to read and interpret the alphabet, which is always possible.